# VoiceProcessingIO while using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, core-audio, avplayer

I'm currently working on an application that has some unusual requirements.

We're trying to record sound from the microphone while playing a video file to the user. This worked great using AVCaptureSession to record from the microphone and AVPlayer to play the video - except the capture session also recorded the video sound and we got terrible feedback/echo.

We next tried to use RemoteIO with the VoiceProcessingIO subtype to record the audio and suppress the echo. This also worked great - except now there is no sound coming from the AVPlayer.

Is it possible to use AudioUnit to record sound while playing video (with sound) on AVPlayer and cancel the echo?

NB: I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919464/using-remote-io-for-recording-and-avplayer-for-playing-ipod-library-audio-at-the) question which has contradicting answers.

Comment: How do you know echo suppression is working great if the `AVPlayer` isn't making any noise?

Comment: We clap and dance :)

Comment: Ah I see. Good point. Our clapping and dancing was probably useless wasn't it...

Comment: No, it's very good for you

Comment: I am not quite understanding your question.  Your system has 1 input ( microphone) and 1 output (speaker).    In your final recording, what sounds do you want?  Do you want only the user's voice recorded from the mic?  Or do you want both the user's voice and the audio that came from the video?    Also, while the video is playing, are you routing the mic to the speaker as well?  If so that will surely make feedback.    Is this app typically used with headphones?

Comment: While the video is playing in AVPlayer, that sound needs to go to the speaker. At the same time we are recording the sound from the mic which is basically the person's response as they watch the video. Then both are composed together and saved as a file. It is used without headphones.